# Offset left in Flot pie chart is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, charts, flot, pie-chart

I want to place the `pie` on the top-left corner of the `chart` but the `left` property is not
working, `top` on the other hand is working.

[My code - Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/canttouchit/wPnYW/1/)

**CODE:**

```
$(function () {
     var data = [
    { label: "Read", data: 50, color: '#614E43' },
    { label: "Unread", data: 150, color: '#F5912D' }];
      $.plot($("#star"), data, 
      {
        series: {

          pie: {        
            radius: 0.2,  
            innerRadius: 0.125,
            show: true,
            stroke: {
                width: 0.1,
                color: '#808080'
            },
            offset: {
                  top: -70,
                  left: -30
            }
          }
        }
      });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the `setupPie()` function. I believe this to be a bug.

The pie plot does not allow a left position lower than the maximum radius, even if the actual radius is smaller.

`http://flot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.flot.pie.js @ line 204`

```
if (centerLeft<maxRadius)
    centerLeft = maxRadius;
else if (centerLeft>canvas.width-maxRadius)
    centerLeft = canvas.width-maxRadius;
```

If you have set a relative radius, it should not check the left against the maximum width.

Instead, there should be something like:

```
//calculate the radius the same way drawPie() does
var radius = options.series.pie.radius;
if (options.series.pie.radius < 1)
    radius *= maxRadius;

//and compare to that value
if (centerLeft < radius)
    centerLeft = radius;
else if (centerLeft > canvas.width-radius)
    centerLeft = canvas.width-radius;
```

### Edit:

I have forked the repo and tried my code, seems to be getting the work done.

My [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/masteram/MB92q/).

Answer (score 2):

As @MasterAM correctly points out, the bug is in the way centerLeft is clipped.  A slightly better solution is to simply move it inside the check for width == "auto", since the clipping is only meant to apply in that case anyway.

Note that the version of Flot you're using, from code.google.com is quite old; we moved to [Github](http://github.com/flot/flot) a while ago.  I've pushed a fix to master, so if you switch to the latest from GH you will be all set.

Comment: Added a pull request. Hope you'll consider it.